# How can I access member's member by memberinfo?

Tags: c#, reflection

my code like below:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        B i=new B();
        MemberInfo[] mis = i.GetType().GetMembers();
        if (mis.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "a") != null)
        {
            MemberInfo mi = mis.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "a");

            // Now I want to access member of a via mi
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public int i { get; set; }
        public void test() { }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public A a { get; set; }
        public B()
        {
            a = new A();
        }
    }
```

I declared class A and class B, and got MemberInfo about `b.a`. Now Can I get a's member via class MemberInfo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MemberInfo object is typically actually one of three subclasses: FieldInfo, PropertyInfo, or MethodInfo. Since these are fundamentally different constructs, you need to access them differently. You can do something like:

```
switch (memberInfo)
{
  case FieldInfo fieldInfo:
    return fieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
  case PropertyInfo propertyInfo:
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
  case MethodInfo methodInfo:
    return methodInfo.Invoke(obj, params...)
}
```

In this situation, obj is the object that you are getting the member from.

Answer (score 0):

MemberInfo gets all types of members within a class. So you will have to filter down to its methods and then find the Method with name `a`.

```
MemberInfo miA = i.GetType().GetMembers().FirstOrDefault(mi => mi.MemberType==MemberTypes.Method && mi.Name == "a");

// Now start using miA for whatever you need
// For example, iterate all of its parameters
foreach ( ParameterInfo pi in ((MethodInfo) mi).GetParameters() )
{
    Display(indent+1, "Parameter: Type={0}, Name={1}", pi.ParameterType, pi.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method like this sample code.

```
 public static class ClassEx
    {
        public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo memberInfo, object forObject)
        {
            switch (memberInfo.MemberType)
            {
                case MemberTypes.Field:
                    return ((FieldInfo)memberInfo).GetValue(forObject);
                case MemberTypes.Property:
                    return ((PropertyInfo)memberInfo).GetValue(forObject);
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

And use in your code like this

```
B i = new B();
            i.a = new A();
            i.a.i = 10;
            MemberInfo[] mis = i.GetType().GetMembers();
            if (mis.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "a") != null)
            {
                MemberInfo mi = mis.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "a");

                A test = (A)mi.GetValue(i);

                // handle A object here
            }
```